# UTC (elastic search) to MomentJs localtime

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, momentjs, utc

I am following an example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FLhpq/4/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=FLhpq) that converts a UTC time to a local momentjs time.

Although my example isn't quite working correctly and I am attempting to understand why.

**My ReactJS code executes the following function to display the proper time:**

```
<p>Created Date: {(this.utcToLocalTime(result._source.created_date))}</p>
```

**The function is as follows (ES6 code):**

```
  utcToLocalTime(utc_time) {
    var localTime = moment.utc(utc_time).toDate()
    console.log(localTime) // Tue Jun 21 2016 16:59:34 GMT-0700 (PDT)

    var localTime_formatted = moment(localTime).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
    console.log(localTime_formatted) //2016-06-21 16:59:34
    return localTime_formatted
  }
```

But I would like the time to show something local like `10:32 AM`

How am I using MomentJS incorrectly?

Comment: So, you are missing the am/pm part? then just use parsing with a or A. or do I get something wrong? see this example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ya1h7zk6/ and the docs for parsing here: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/

Comment: You do not need to call `toDate` or reload a `Date` object.  Just call `.local()` and then format from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question, you want to parse the date from somehwat "normal" format to am/pm (12h system). To do so, just add an `a` at the end of your localTime_formatted Template like this:

```
utcToLocalTime(utc_time) {
    var localTime = moment.utc(utc_time).toDate()
    console.log(localTime) // Tue Jun 21 2016 16:59:34 GMT-0700 (PDT)

    var localTime_formatted = moment(localTime).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm a')
    console.log(localTime_formatted) //2016-06-21 16:59:34
    return localTime_formatted
  }
```

I updated your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ya1h7zk6/

And here's a link to the momentjs parsing-documentation: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/

**edit:** by the way, you said "ES6 Code". Then please use `let` ( [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) ) instead of var ;)

Comment: Thank you, and you are right I should be using `let`.